# Does Spring wait for each @PostConstruct to finish when loading ApplicationContext

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have some logic of loading data from the DB in @PostConstruct method in some of the service classes which takes a long time.

And there are some unrelated controllers which load quite quickly and could potentially start accepting HTTP requests.

So the question, does Spring just wait for each @PostConstruct method to return when loading the ApplicationContext, hence can't accept any requests, or are there any exceptions?

I know, I could load the data from DB asynchronously, but perhaps there're brighter solutions?

Comment: Good question. I would imagine that as soon as an MVC controller bean has been initialized it's in theory available to be hit by http requests. However in practice the embedded servlet engine (Spring Boot) or app server servlet engine won't be available until the context is initialised so you should be OK; loading data in post constructs is a common pattern.

Comment: I just did a quick test. Looks like `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`(through which REST endpoints are actualized)  kicks in after  `@PostContruct`. So it should be fine.

Comment: Another quick point, Loading data from DB on startup using `@PostConstruct` is a common thing. But mostly it is config data. But if you are loading a lot of data on startup, you might have to think of an alternative.

Comment: @pvpkiran Yep, it's a lot of data. The only alternative i thought of is to call the data loading in different thread from the PostConstruct.. but maybe there are better ways?

Comment: The other thing to ask is why are you loading a lot of data at start up ? Often a good alternative is to cache data via @Cacheable annotations, and if you want the cache pre-initialized, do this in a ContextRefreshedEvent application listener

Comment: @Paul i cache the data once I load them from DB (in google cache).
well, it's a bit complicated, but since you ask :) There are 3-days worth of data that needs to be loaded from the DB.. the first 2-days-data must be loaded before accepting any requests; the 3rd-day-data can be loaded simultaneously with serving HTTP requests.

Comment: @pvpkiran your comment is more like an answer which I would accept. can you post your answer?

Comment: @user3082046 sure. Just did.

Comment: @PaulNUK your answers were pretty helpful as well so thanks for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spring all the REST endpoint are actualized through `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` class.

And this kicks in after `@PostContruct`. So the way you are doing is perfectly fine.